# Forward from Apache to nginx listening on different port

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4

I have both Apache and nginx installed and running on an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server at Digital Ocean. Apache is listening on port 80 and nginx on port 8080. Thus, the following http requests work:

```
www.mysite.org/
www.mysite.org:8080/
```

with the first site served up by Apache and the second served by nginx.  I would prefer the sites to be responsive to something like:

```
www.mysite.org
www2.mysite.org
```

but I've not been able to get that to work yet.  I do understand the basics of virtual hosts as described in [Apache's documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html). In particular, I can get those sites working if they're both served by apache with the content served from different document roots. But what Apache configuration will send requests to `www2` over to a different port served by the nginx server?

Comment: search in the top right is your friend.

Comment: @Iain Thanks! I agree that looks like like a dup and marked it as such. I look forward to trying it out later. I did search, incidentally. With some 12,000 hits for 'Apache and nginx', however, I didn't find that question. Thanks again!